# Is it a correct math definition of averaging two vectors? (Blender vector math node)

Tags: node-editor, mathematics, vector

There is such a definition in the Blender Vector Math node:

[image]

Isn't an average vector supposed to be something like:

> Vector = (input1+input2)/n

where n is a number of vectors?

It seems what we really get from the blender vector math node is a normalized sum, not an average vector. Is that right?

Comment: I agree that this does seem to be odd and unexpected behaviour for 'Average' - I don't understand what that current implementation would actually be useful for. I'd suggest perhaps raising it as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The *Average* operator was initially added to Blender as a way to get a *Unit Angle Bisector*, which is a unit vector that bisects the angle between the two input vectors. The operator assumes that both input vectors are unit vectors, otherwise, it will not work as expected.

Due to the misleading name and the ambiguity of operation. The *Average* operator has been removed in Blender 2.81. Thought it might be added again in the future in a more clear form.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Omar - that makes sense.